# How to reduce DStream data from kafka in scala?

Tags: scala

I have some DStream data from kafka streaming and I want to reduce in require format using scala.
Please provide me hint to get the proper format for given DStream data.

For example:

```
case class Test(cust: String, labNo: String, device: String, properties: String, maxValue: Int, count: Int)]

DStream[((cust_1,lab2, switch,cpu,90,2),
         (cust_1,lab2, switch,cpu,80,4),
         (cust_1,lab2, ap,cpu,70,4),
         (cust_1,lab2, switch,mem,70,3),
         (cust_1,lab1, switch,cpu,90,2),
         (cust_1,lab1, switch,cpu,70,4),
         (cust_1,lab1, switch,cpu,80,4),
         (cust_1,lab1, ap,mem,70,3))]
```

format (k, v) and apply the
Groupbykey(cust, lab) =>

Get the following expected out:

```
(cust_1, lab2), ArrayBuffer((switch, cpu, 90, 2), (switch,cpu,80,4), (ap,cpu,70,4), (switch,mem,70,3))
(cust_1, lab1), ArrayBuffer((switch, cpu 90, 2), (switch,cpu,70,4), (switch,cpu,80,4), (ap,mem,70,3))
```

GroupbyKey(device) inside ArrayBuffer:

```
(cust_1, lab12), ArrayBuffer((switch -> ((cpu, 90, 2), (cpu,80,4),(mem,70,3)), ap -> (cpu,70,4)))
(cust_1, lab1), ArrayBuffer((switch -> ((cpu 90, 2), (cpu,70,4), (cpu,80,4)), ap->(mem,70,3))
```

GroupbyKey(Properties) for each device:

```
(cust_1, lab12), ArrayBuffer((switch -> (cpu -> ((90, 2), (80,4)), mem ->(70,3))), ap -> (cpu,70,4)))
(cust_1, lab1), ArrayBuffer((switch -> (cpu -> ((90, 2), (70,4), (80,4)))), ap->(mem,70,3)))
```

I'm giving above example to explaining the requirement. The example is not executed so please ignore any Scala output format.

So final output looks like:

```
result {
   cust: "xyz"
   labNo: 2
   device {
      switch {
             cpu {
                 maxValue: 80
                 count: 4
                 },
             cpu {
                 maxValue: 90
                 count: 2
                 }
              mem {
                maxValue: 70
                count: 3
                }
      }
      ap {
             cpu {
                 maxValue: 70
                 count: 4
                 }
              mem {
                maxValue: 70
                count: 3
                }
      }

   }
}
```